# update sql table for Active Directory createdon and disabled on information

Tags: sql, powershell, active-directory

I have a user table in the database that i am trying to update with Createdon date and disabled on date with the data from Active Directory. So far this is what I have:

```
$SearchRoot = "OU=NonAIQ,OU=FrontOffice,DC=dev,DC=local"
$serverName = "localhost"

#$SearchRoot = "OU=NonAIQ,OU=FrontOffice,DC=dmz,DC=local"
#$serverName = "spoproddb3.dmz.local"


try {
Import-Module "sqlps" -DisableNameChecking

if ((Get-PSSnapin -Name "Quest.ActiveRoles.ADManagement" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null ) {
    Add-PsSnapin "Quest.ActiveRoles.ADManagement"
}

$externalUsers = Get-QADUser -SizeLimit 0 -SearchRoot $SearchRoot | Select-Object whencreated, whenchanged
$externalUsers | % {
    $query = @"
Update tbl_EdgeUsers Set CompanyName = '$_.CreationDate'
Where UserUPN = $_.UserPrincipalName;
"@
    Write-Host "The query is $query"

    Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance $serverName -Query $query -Database "EdgeDW"
}
} finally {
Remove-Module "sqlps" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Remove-PsSnapin "Quest.ActiveRoles.ADManagement"
}
```

Now for when created, we just grab all the values.

But since AD does not track the Disabled in date, I am using the when changed date since we dont make changes to an account once it is changed.

The part that I am stuck on is about the logic for when changed date. For this I have to check if an account is disabled. If it is the update the table with that date. If an account is not disabled, then ignore that value and set the value in the sql table as '1/1/9999'.

can you guys please help with this logic?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

of top of my head maybe something such as this, although thinking about it now, its a nasty way having the invoke-sql inside the foreach loop if the dataset is large, probably better to output the results of the if statement to csv or somewhere then run the invoke-sql against that.

```
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties whenchanged | Select-Object -Property UserPrincipalName, whenchanged, enabled
$disabledsql = @"
update tbl_EdgeUsers Set date = '$user.whenchanged'
Where UserUPN = '$user.UserPrincipalName';
"@
$activesql = @"
update tbl_EdgeUsers Set date = '1/1/9999
Where UserUPN = '$user.UserPrincipalName';
"@
foreach ($user in $users) 
{
  if ($user.enabled -eq 'False') 
  {
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $serverName -Query $disabledsql -Database 'EdgeDW'
  }
  else 
  {
   Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $serverName -Query $activesql -Database 'EdgeDW'
  }
}
```

Comment: Cool. Thanks dude!